# Change date text to date

Tags: java, android

I want to change my date text (7 Apr 2013) to date (2013-04-07) in eclipse android

My function now :

```
DateFormat fmtDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d_start = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        date.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        date.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateLabel();
    }
}; 
private void updateLabel() {
    dateLabel.setText(fmtDate.format(date.getTime()));
```

}

How i can change format date like 2013-04-07? I don't have a many idea. Thank's

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to replace your `fmtDate` by

```
DateFormat fmtDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use SimpleDateFormatter instead, so replace this line

```
DateFormat fmtDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
```

with

```
SimpleDateFormat fmtDate =
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

For more information, give [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) a look